# Error when declaring an HtmlPage using HTMLUnit

Tags: java, angularjs, htmlunit

When I use this code:

```
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_45)) {
            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.chemicalformula.org/calculators/chemical-formula-calculator");}
```

I get this error:

```
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: '*,:x' error: Invalid selector: :x).] sourceName=[http://www.chemicalformula.org/sites/all/themes/chemical_formula_2/jquery.js] line=[4] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
```

I've seen threads with people saying it's AngularJS, but the thing is that I cannot edit the code on that website, so I can't fix it by changing the website code.

I have tried using other browser versions, but they all return the same error.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this is only a log message that informs about the call of an invalid selector from jQuery.
This is not your problem.

The error starts after that line (and for future posts provide as much information as possible).

In the end the error is

```
TypeError: Cannot find function getComputedTextLength in object [object HTMLUnknownElement]
```

This looks like a HtmlUnit bug. Please open an issue in the HtmlUnit bugtracker.

Answer (score 0):

We made a fix in between. You can use the latest snapshot build (from maven or via download from our ci server).